# Does a certain quartic quadrivariate polynomial fall within any known category?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-information

I've encountered the following quartic quadrivariate polynomial,
\begin{equation}
\left(w^2-1\right) x^2-w^2-2 w x y z+\left(y^2-1\right) \left(z^2-1\right).
\end{equation}
Does it correspond to any recognizable, previously-studied surface (if equated to 0)?

This polynomial appears in a certain quantum-information-theoretic context, pertaining to the probability (with respect to Hilbert-Schmidt measure) that a two-qubit system is separable/disentangled.

Comment: Might this question be more appropriate for [math.SE]?

Comment: Thanks, ACuriousMind! I had, in fact, asked it (without the last paragraph) on Mathematics. But questions there lately that I post don't seem to get much viewership/reaction--in substantial contrast to Mathematica.stack.exchange. (Maybe MathOverFlow might be, in general, more appropriate. I have largely been trying to avoid multiple postings, after having once been scolded for doing so.) I did think the question might get some reaction from mathematical physicists acquainted with Kummer,...,surfaces.